# GridviewLayoutManager with headers

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on an app

I have implemented a working recycler view that receives a jsonarray, passes the data to a string array.

I now want to add section headers to the layout manager.

I have read two schools of thought on this:
- Change the spansize of the view to match the total columns of the grid
- create a custom adapter that loads a different view if the item is a section header.

Im not sure which way to go with this and its starting to confuse me

I have a list of data in an array which includes both headers and grid data (myDataset), i have also created another array with the mapping for the dataset in (myDatamap). In myDatamap i have a list of field types (1 for header and 0 for griddata. I was hoping to pass both arrays to the adaptor and for it decide if its a header or a griditem and then load the appropriate view.

I am leaning more towards loading a different view for the header items, allowing for me to customise the layout of the header easier.

Here is my adaptor code

```
package com.example.alex.recyclerview2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mDatamap;

    private Context context;
    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public ImageView imgImage;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            imgImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
    }

    public void add(int position, String item) {
        mDataset.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(String item) {
        int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset, ArrayList<Integer> myDatamap) {mDataset = myDataset;myDatamap=mDatamap; }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, parent, false);

        context = v.getContext();

        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final String name = mDataset.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.500kgiveaway.co.uk/" + name).resize(200,200).into(holder.imgImage);

//        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        holder.txtHeader.setText(name);

        holder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                remove(name);
            }
        });

        holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ive not had much interest in this post but here is the answer

i hope this help someone else

What i have done is implemented a custom view adaptor to manage the item types

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ElementsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mDatamap;

    public Context context;

    private static final int VIEW_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_NORMAL = 1;

    private View headerView;
    private int datasetSize;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        public ImageView imgImage;


        //header
        public TextView headertext;

        public ViewHolder(View v, int viewType) {
            super(v);

           switch (viewType){
                case 1:
                    txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                    txtFooter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                    imgImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
               case 0:
                    headertext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headertext);
           }
        }

    }

    public ElementsAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset, ArrayList<Integer> myDatamap) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mDatamap = myDatamap;
    }

      @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isHeader(position) == 1 ? VIEW_HEADER : VIEW_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_HEADER) {
            // create a new view
            View sub_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);

            Context context = sub_view.getContext();

            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(sub_view,viewType);

            return vh;


//            return new HeaderViewHolder(headerView);

        } else {
            // create a new view
            View sub_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sub_layout, parent, false);

            context = sub_view.getContext();

            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(sub_view, viewType);

            return vh;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (isHeader(position) == 1) {

            // - get element from your dataset at this position
            // - replace the contents of the view with that element
            final String name = mDataset.get(position);

//        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
            viewHolder.headertext.setText(name);

        } else {

    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final String name = mDataset.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.500kgiveaway.co.uk/"+name).resize(200,200).into(viewHolder.imgImage);

//        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    viewHolder.txtHeader.setText(name);

    viewHolder.txtHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
        //remove(name);
    }
    }

    );

    viewHolder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: "+mDataset.get(position));
}

        //ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
        //holder.textView.setText("Position " + (position - 1));
    }

    public int isHeader(int position) {
        return mDatamap.get(position) ==1 ? 1:0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use both solutions? If you set the span size you can easily set a textview or whatever you want the header to be.

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return adapter.isHeader(position) ? gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount() : 1;
            }
        });
```

Then in the adapter have a general class Item that says if the item is a header and has some information about the real item that should be shown, in my case since I have image paths for showing images and titles for headers I just use a attribute text but you can use something like `int realPositionInTheirLists` since headers titles and images paths are in two separate lists:

```
private static class Item {

    public boolean isHeader;

    public String text;

    public Item(String text, boolean isHeader) {
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Then you have something like this on the methods that tell which type of item it is:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position).isHeader ? VIEW_TYPE_HEADER : VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT;
}

public boolean isHeader(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position).isHeader;
}
```

Then finally on the two methods that inflate the view and bind the data you inflate the view that you want depending on whether it is a header or not and bind the data using the Item class:

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_header, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Item item = mItems.get(position);

    holder.bindItem(item, position);
}
```

Being the holder.bindItem a method of the ViewHolder class. There you can choose however you want to separate both views.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll give this a go and let you know the results. Thanks for you help